# Pandas, How to subtract first row value from all values in a Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series object in Pandas and I would like to subtract a number equal to the first value of the Series from all values of the Series.

For example:

This:

```
2015-10-01: 5000
2015-10-02: 5005
2015-10-03: 5012
```

becomes this:

```
2015-10-01: 0
2015-10-02: 5
2015-10-03: 12
```

Is this possible with a native Pandas method? Or should I loop through all values and subtract?

Comment: just do `s - s.iloc[0]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the first row value using `iloc[0]` and then just subtract from the rest of the series:

```
In [5]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""2015-10-01 5000
2015-10-02 5005
2015-10-03 5012"""
s = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], header=None, delim_whitespace=True, squeeze=True)
s

Out[5]:
0
2015-10-01    5000
2015-10-02    5005
2015-10-03    5012
Name: 1, dtype: int64

In [6]:    
s - s.iloc[0]

Out[6]:
0
2015-10-01     0
2015-10-02     5
2015-10-03    12
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

It's possible to use `head(1)` but you need to index the array in order to get the scalar value otherwise you get `NaN` for the 2nd row onwards due to index alignment:

```
In [9]:
s - s.head(1)[0]

Out[9]:
0
2015-10-01     0
2015-10-02     5
2015-10-03    12
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

compare with:

```
In [10]:
s - s.head(1)

Out[10]:
0
2015-10-01     0
2015-10-02   NaN
2015-10-03   NaN
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```